# wrap each image in a div and prepend a number

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to write a function to wrap each image in a div and then insert a span with label for each image.

This is what I have written so far:

```
$('#carousel img').each(function(index) {
  $(this).wrap('<div class="image"></div>');
  $(this).before(function (index) {
    index = '00' + (index + 1);
    return '<span class=index>' + index.substr(index.length - 2) + '</span>';
  });
});
```

What my code is actually doing is this, notice the **number problem** and putting the **span inside the img tag**:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="img/ny1.jpg" />
    <span class="index">01</span>   
  </img>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <img src="img/ny2.jpg" />
    <span class="index">01</span>   
  </img>
</div>
```

**The desired result of this:**

From this:

`<img src="img/ny1.jpg" />`
`<img src="img/ny2.jpg" />`

To this:

```
<div class="image">
<span class="index">01</span>   
<img src="img/ny1.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="image">
<span class="index">02</span>   
<img src="img/ny1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: The problem is it puts the span inside the img wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem you're having is with the numbering (because I see nothing else wrong), then remove `index` from `$(this).before(function (index) {`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wAzBJ/)**